# NSB - Send/Reply same application

Tags: nservicebus

Is it possible to configure NSB in a Send/Reply config such that the same application is responsible for both sending the message and processing/replying to the same message?  The goal would be to leverage the durability of messaging provided by NSB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can either use the bus.SendLocal short cut or configure the messages with the address of your local input queue. SendLocal is probably what you want